# Can anyone identify this broad-leafed weed/plant for me?

Tags: identification, weeds

This weed has been growing in my south-facing garden (London, UK - within 0.5 mile of woodlands and wetlands) for a few weeks now. It started as a low-lying cluster of broad leaves (a bit like a flat cabbage) but has now grown into a monster so I need to dig it out before it takes over my rose bed. It looks quite nice, broad green leaves and delicate blue flowers that seem to attract quite a few bees, and it even smells nice... but it's got to go!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the leaves are unpleasant/rough to touch, it's *Pentaglottis sempervirens*, common name green alkanet, see here https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=1001. Its very common throughout  most of the UK, particularly in the south.

Despite the attractive flowers, extract it asap - it puts down deep roots which can be difficult to dig out completely - it will regrow from any root left behind, and it seeds itself freely.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be field forget-me-not, *Myosotis avensis*? Here some info from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myosotis_arvensis), to check if it matches.